# Creating bar plot using dataframe with multi-indexing

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot, multi-index

I have the following dataFrame:

```
         Score
one  A     8
     B    19
     D    29
two  C    18
     A    10
     B     4
     D     2
six  C     4
     A     4
     B     4
```

And I wish to create **one** bar plot where X axis values are "one", "two" and "six", and each value has 4 bars (A,B,C,D) when the bar height determined by the score column.

Thank you.
Nastya

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshaping with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.unstack()['Score'].plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
df.unstack(level=1).plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: Thanks! The graph worked, however why in the legend I have values like - (0,A), (0,B),(0,C) and(0,D), instead A,B,C,and D? Is it possible to print above each bar A/B/C/D ?